# File "enumitem.sty"not found error is comming

Tags: errors

I am using MikTex 2.9 with TeXworks for composing project report on windows 8. The errors are coming:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `enumitem.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `tikz.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `eso-pic.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `pdfpages.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `fancyhdr.sty' not found.
! LaTeX Error: File `fancybox.sty' not found.
```

What should i do to remove these errors? I searched .shy files in my folder but files are not exist.

Comment: please reply as early as possible. Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems as though you have not installed these packages on your machine. You can do so via the [Package Manager](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/pkgmgt.html). If you did not change the settings of your installation an on-the-fly installation should also be possible. But that does not seem to work. Try to [update your distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864).

Comment: I am using Windows 8. please tell me how to install packages via package manager on windows 8

Comment: Do you have a *Start menu* (I don't know Windows 8)?

Comment: If the search for "Package Manager" doesn't turn up anything, try  finding the binary, on my machine it lives in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\mpm_mfc_admin.exe`

Answer (score 3):

Start with the usual desktop.  Then you have the Windows 8 button as first symbol at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Click on it to change to the Apps listing.  It depends how you have changed the apps start page.

[image]

If you can't see the symbol for MiKTeX package Manager (last symbol in picture above) click on the little white arrow pointing down at the bottom. If you can't see it move the mouse at the bootom of the screen.

Then you get the hole list of installed programs or apps.  Search there for the heading MiKTeX 2.9.  There you will find the needed app.